# Функция генератора случайных чисел

Tags: php

Подскажите функцию генерации случайных чисел на `php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если на php то `mt_rand(1,n);`

Comment: можно и `rand(1,n);`

Answer (score 3):

```
rand($min, $max);//где $min - минимальное, $max максимальное
```

Comment: @AlexWindHope а в чем же разница между rand(1,n) и mt_rand(1,n);

Comment: php.net в помощь, я не справочник...<br> Коротко - mt_rand работает немного быстрее(незначительно) а rand красивее пишеться :)<br>
Если по умному то неплохо расписано <a href="http://groups.google.com/group/fido7.ru.php.chainik/browse_thread/thread/e96161fddc9ec63f?pli=1">здесь</a>